# TemplatesController error related to webfont!

Tags: 404, logs

I'm getting a very strange 404 error on my live site:

> Craft\HttpException: template = fonts/BlissBold-webfont.ttf in  /path/to/mydomain/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:72

I've searched my complete directory and the only reference to BlissBold-webfont.ttf is in a stylesheet.  How on earth is this affecting the TemplatesController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemplateController is what all template requests in Craft get routed through.

That error just means that someone/something is trying to load a resource (in your case `yoursite.com/fonts/BlissBold-webfont.ttf`) and that doesn't exist on your file system and Craft has no idea how to resolve that request, so it issues a `404 Not Found` in response.

It's more of an informational thing than anything and not really an error.

In the upcoming Craft 3, 404's get logged in separate files so as not to clutter up the main logs.